# mod_ssl: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!] (System error follows)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http, ssl-certificate, https

in my error_log I'm getting following msg

```
[error] mod_ssl: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!] (System error follows)
```

IE wouldn't even load page, yet firefox works fine

Comment: What are the versions you are testing on? IE6 had notorious problems with SSL.

Comment: My machine is Windows XP SP3 and IE7

Comment: Did you get any pop ups with authentication problems?

Comment: nope, nothing of that nature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something was up w/ certificates, after replacing them it start working fine so it was some misconfiguration on my end